# Expect sudo - comand

Tags: expect

This is piece of `expect` code with mistakes. In a few words, I must connect to the first server, and then jump on the second server, make `su -` to enable changing the data on this server, all using  `expect`.

```
spawn ssh -J  root@$GATEWAY_ADDRESS litp-admin@$HOST_ADDRESS
   expect "assword: "
   send   "12shroot\r"
   expect "assword: "
   send   "12shroot\r"
   expect "~]$ "
   send   "su -\r"
   expect "~assword:"
   send   "12shroot\r"
   send   "date -s $NEW_DATE_TIME\r"
```

What are the possible solutions or examples?

I have not found the right solution.